# Display list of lines below text

Tags: html, css

If you visit [link1](http://sbdevelopers.kidsdial.com/seamless-pattern-roses-and-freesia-apple-iphone-4-phone-case.html) & search for text "Info" using CTRL + F, you can see List of lines are displaying below text " **Delivery info**"
. This is right.

[image]

but in [link2](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com/seamless-pattern-roses-and-freesia-apple-iphone-4-phone-case.html) , its displaying in same line as text "Delivery info"

[image]

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1224px)
.add-to-cart-wrapper li {
    color: #908983;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 25px;
    list-style: inside disc;
}
```

when i tried with `position : relative; top : 10px;` line is displaying in right side.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a [**link to an example or site**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: @Paulie_D its really good that you have concern about the site, but as we are using magento site, its very difficult to create code snippet as it is combination of lot of php & html codes combined. i will try to reproduce the problem in question itself from next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paragraph `<p>` (second link) has style `float: left;`. Remove it.